# Over a commutative unital ring, does $\det A = 0$ imply that $A\mathbf{x} = 0$ has a non-zero solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, determinant

This is a standard theorem in linear algebra over fields that is [still true when working over an integral domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2875719/167197).

> For a commutative unital integral domain $R$, let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $R$. The system of linear equations $A\mathbf{x}=0$ has a non-zero solution if and only if $\det(A) = 0$.

The forward direction of this statement is *not* true though if we are working over a ring $R$ that is not an integral domain, a counter example being 
$$
R = \boldsymbol{Z}_6 
\qquad 
A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0  \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} 
\qquad 
\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
\,.
$$

But what about the other direction? Does $\det(A) = 0$ imply that $A\mathbf{x} = 0$ has a non-zero solution over an arbitrary commutative unital ring? I've played around for a bit, and have yet to find a counterexample.

Comment: How do you define determinant over an arbitrary ring?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you're right. Let's limit this to commutative unital rings. Looking at the definition of $\det$, *the unique alternating $R$-multilinear form that sends $I_n$ to $1_R$ ...*, it does require commutative. But now I'm curious how badly things go if you try to define the (left-)determinate in terms of the usual algorithm, where you'd multiply each element of a row on the left by the $\det$ of the corresponding minor, if you don't have a commutative unital ring.

Comment: @MikePierce Determinants cannot be defined over noncommutative rings. There is a similar tool for division rings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieudonné_determinant

Comment: I found this where Sylvia's theorem are trying to prove https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82216288.pdf

Comment: See this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71740/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-trivial-kernel-of-a-matrix-over-a-commuta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $A$ be square of size
$n \times n$, and $\det A=0$. Then $A\,\textrm{adj}(A)=0$ where $\textrm{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate of $A$.
As long as $\textrm{adj}(A)\neq 0$ then taking some column of $\textrm{adj}(A)$ gives you $x$ with
$Ax=0$.

But what if adj$(A)=0$? In this case all minors of $A$ vanish. Find
a largest square submatrix of $A$ with nonzero determinant. We can assume
that it's size $r$ by $r$ and fills the top left corner of $A$.
Let $B$
be the top-left $r+1$ by $r+1$ submatrix of $A$. Then $\det B=0$ but
adj$(B)\ne0$. Let $y$ be the $(r+1)$-th column of adj$(B)$ and $z$ be the column
vector of height $n$ got by appending zeroes below $y$. Then $z\ne0$
(due to the non-vanishing of the top left $r$ by $r$
determinant) and I claim that $Az=0$.

The top $r+1$ entries of $Az$ are certainly zero. This is the identity
$B\,$adj$(B)=0$. If we look at another entry, say the $s$-th then
it is zero, essentially by replacing the bottom row of $B$ by the first $r+1$-th
entries of the $s$-th row of $A$, and noting that the new matrix has zero
determinant, as it is obtained from a submatrix of $A$ of size $r+1$
by $r+1$ by elementary row operations. As all submatrices of $A$ of this
size have vanishing determinant, this completes the proof that $Az=0$.

Comment: Very nice! I'd say that the $s$-th entry is zero because it is the determinant of the submatrix of $A$ of size $r+1$ by $r+1$ obtained by replacing the bottom row of $B$ by the first $r+1$-th entries of the $s$-th row of $A$. See also the references at the end of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71755/660.

Answer (score 5):

In a commutative ring (with 1), it turns out that, yes, $Ax=0$ has a non-trivial solution if and only if $\det(A)$ is either zero or a zero divisor. This follows from a theorem of McCoy.

Here is a link to a related question of my own:

MSE -- [Do these matrix rings have non-zero elements that are neither units nor zero divisors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71235/do-these-matrix-rings-have-non-zero-elements-that-are-neither-units-nor-zero-div)

MO -- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77816/do-these-matrix-rings-have-non-zero-elements-that-are-neither-units-nor-zero-divi

A link to a paper with an account of McCoy's rank theorem: http://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/amspfaff.pdf

Answer (score -2):

Consider $\pmatrix{2&3\cr 2&3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6$ its determinant is $0$, and $2x+3y=0$ implies that $2x=3y$. But the multiples of $2$ are $\{0,2,4\}$ and the multiples of $3$ are $\{0,3\}$.

Comment: The solution can use the fact that $2$ and $3$ are zero-divisors though. So $\langle 3,2\rangle$ is a non-zero solution. This is just an example of the statement being true.